# Am I able to delete a domain name

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I manage a number of domain names with Network Solutions. I've transferred out all the domains that are or will be used. However, there are some left which were bought speculatively and will never be used.

Is it possible to have them deleted, that is, have the registrations deleted?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you're hoping for your money back, that's not likely. If you're not, just wait and the registrations will expire. If in the meantime someone comes up to you wanting to buy one, so much the better.

Comment: No, not wanting a refund. Chance would be a fine thing ;-) I realise they'll expire. But was wandering if someone had done this. I'd like to close the account... One less set of account details and one less company with our CC details.

Comment: Just make sure (if applicable) you have set your account to not auto renew.